# Changing restricted fields of templates in kubernetes and openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm using the openshift playground. I deploy a sample application, and export the yaml for the pod.
While trying to edit some of the fields I ran across this message
`Forbidden: unsafe sysctl "kernel.msgmax" is not allowed`

Searching around the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#listing-all-sysctl-parameters describes how some parameters are labelled unsafe and cannot be changed but the safe ones can

But even the safe sysctls throw error,

```
spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than spec.containers[*].image, spec.initContainers[*].image, spec.activeDeadlineSeconds or spec.tolerations
```

1. Is it the playground environment that is limiting changes to kernel parameters? Would I need to have my own minikube installation to enable changing the unsafe sysctl parameters?
2. Apart from the minikube/kubelet alternatives given to edit/enable unsafe sysctls, is there a different way? What would be a good way to customize kernel parameters for a pod?

Answer (score 1):

The safe sysctls throwing that error is expected behavior. What you need to do is delete the pod before applying the edited yaml to the cluster.You can also avoid this error if you use a deployment instead of a pod directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please read thoroughly [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/) documentation section. Everything is clearly explained there.

As to setting **Unsafe Sysctls**, you need to additionally enable them on node-level:

> All *safe* sysctls are enabled by default.
>
> All *unsafe* sysctls are disabled by default and must be allowed
>   manually by the cluster admin on a per-node basis. Pods with disabled
>   unsafe sysctls will be scheduled, but will fail to launch.
>
> With the warning above in mind, the cluster admin can allow certain
>   *unsafe* sysctls for very special situations such as high-performance or real-time application tuning. *Unsafe* sysctls are enabled on a
>   node-by-node basis with a flag of the kubelet; for example:
>
> ```
> kubelet --allowed-unsafe-sysctls \
>   'kernel.msg*,net.core.somaxconn' ...
> ```
>
> For Minikube, this can be done via the `extra-config` flag:
>
> ```
> minikube start --extra-config="kubelet.allowed-unsafe-sysctls=kernel.msg*,net.core.somaxconn"...
> ```
>
> Only *namespaced* sysctls can be enabled this way.

As to...

> But even the safe sysctls throw error,
>
> ```
> spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than spec.containers[*].image, spec.initContainers[*].image, spec.activeDeadlineSeconds or spec.tolerations
> ```

This is completely different error message and it has nothing to do with restrictions related to changing sysctls in your `Pod` definition. Note that you cannot change majority of your `Pod` specification via `kubectl edit` apart from just a few exceptions listed in the message above. Specifically you cannot change them without recreating your `Pod` so in this case instead of editing it you can simply run:

```
kubectl get pod pod-name -o yaml > my-pod.yaml
```

Then you can edit your required `Pod` spec fields, and redeploy it:

```
kubectl apply -f my-pod.yaml
```

Alternatively you may edit your `Deployment` as @Arghya Sadhu already suggested in his answer. `Deployment controller` will recreate those `Pods` for you with updated specification.

---

> Is it the playground environment that is limiting changes to kernel
>   parameters? Would I need to have my own minikube installation to
>   enable changing the unsafe sysctl parameters?

Not really. You can enable them on every node which is part of your cluster by re-configuring your **kubelets**. As to changing **kubelet** configuration, it might be done differently depending on your **kubernetes installation**. In case it was created with **kubeadm** you just need to edit the following file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

then run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and restart your kubelet by running:

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

> Apart from the minikube/kubelet alternatives given to edit/enable
>   unsafe sysctls, is there a different way? What would be a good way to
>   customize kernel parameters for a pod?

Answered above.

I hope it clarified your doubts about setting both *safe* and *unsafe* sysctls in a **Kubernetes Cluster**.